# Upload an image to kraken.io which saves to amazon s3 using Angular2 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, amazon-s3, firebase-realtime-database, kraken-image-optimizer

The kraken.io docs specify how to save using node and php. I've successfully managed to store images to the amazon bucket but I'm struggling to implement the image optimization part with kraken.io

I'm using firebase as a database for now.

Is it possible to use node's implementation on the frontend itself?

The docs are here: https://kraken.io/docs/storage-s3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ng-img-tools and ng-img-max instead of kraken.io to get desired outcome.